# No module named 'zstandard.backend_c'

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, datadog, zstandard

Im trying to submit datadog metrics using package `datadog_api_client.v2.api.metrics_api`, But while submitting the metrics, i'm getting error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zstandard.backend_c'` although i have zstandard package installed.

My installed packages are as below, and ive tried different other versions as well.

```
Python 3.9.6 
datadog-api-client==2.14.0 
urllib3==1.26.8 
zstandard==0.21.0
```

This is how i submit my metrics to datadog,

```
from datadog_api_client import ApiClient, Configuration
from datadog_api_client.v2.api.metrics_api import MetricsApi
api_client = ApiClient(my_credentials)
metrics_api = MetricsApi(api_client)
metrics_api.submit_metrics(content_encoding=MetricContentEncoding.ZSTD1,body=MetricPayload(series=my_metrics_list))
```

Error i get,
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zstandard.backend_c'`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when I was running my script on MacOS. But then it worked perfectly fine on Amazon Linux.

Comment: This answer does not provide a solution to OP's problem, please try and post an appropriate answer that encloses OP's use case by not requiring them to switch operating systems.